# autocomplete(alt+'/') does not work after installing eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

After re-installation,the eclipse does not give me a list of proposals when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in the editor.
But there is a notification sound after pressing.
I checked `preference->java->editor->content assist->advanced`,all the proposals are on.
And I also checked `preference->general->keys`,which is correctly configured.
Now how do i fix the problem please?

Comment: in juno this is a known bug evry 1 facing the same

Answer (score 0):

I think autocomplete is used by ctrl+space

Comment: This could have been posted as an Comment.